# Invoke powershell cmdlet dynamically with object parameter values

Tags: c#, powershell

I have created custom PowerShell cmdlets and I am writing a test script for them.

I get the list of cmdlets and I have to pass it an object of non-string type. I tried using Invoke-Expression but I get an error where it uses the string name for the parameter value.

```
$cmd = @()
$cmd += Get-Cmdlet1
$cmd += Get-Cmdlet2
$cmd += Get-Cmdlet3
foreach($c in $cmd)
{   
    $ret1 =  $c + " -connection "
    $ret = Invoke-Expression "$ret1 $($conn)"
    $ret >> C:\Output.txt
}
```

$conn is a custom SSH connection object(not a PowerShell object type).
I get the error

```
Invalid input: System.String is not supported
Parameter name: Connection
```

How can I invoke such a command with name and object parameter added dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$cmd = @()
$cmd += Get-Command Get-Cmdlet1
$cmd += Get-Command Get-Cmdlet2
$cmd += Get-Command Get-Cmdlet3
foreach($c in $cmd)
{   
    &$c -connection $conn >> C:\output.txt
}
```

If you put `$conn` in a double-quoted string, PowerShell will convert that object to a string.  Also, this `$cmd = Get-Cmdlet1` executes `Get-Cmdlet1`.  Not sure if that is what you intended as you seem to want to execute the cmdlet inside the foreach loop.